# React renders JSX elements incomplete - recursive render

Tags: reactjs, multidimensional-array, jsx, conditional-rendering

I have a pretty specific case where my react component renders only a part of what is returned by the code.

**General Idea:** 
I have a multidimentsional array: 
Rows and Columns [][] of a not specified size, starting with 1 predefined element. 
Each column contains one object of another set of components, which is supposed to be drawn conditionally / differently based on the type of the component.

To be able to read the code more easily i have splitted the `array.map()` calls into seperate functions. 
At the end in the `return` of my component function (using a functional component here) I am only calling one function which does recursively generate JSX code to be filled in at once.

I did find [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34867236/react-recursively-render-nested-elements) which seems to be really similar to what i want to do. 
In my code I am basically doing the same things, however React does not seem to render the Elements correctly.

**The Issue:** 
React gets multiple elements back from `React.CreateElement()` each at a time. 
In the end the code is supposed to have a nested render of the multiple elements.

But only the first one `Row` is rendered and appears in the DOM correctly. 
The corresponding `Column` which is supposed to be nested, does not appear in the DOM at all.
From further testing i can say that the components Functions `Column` and the following element is never executed. 
The JS-Object which is returned from JSX and CreateElement is correct though: 
It contains the Children in its properties as it should. Its just never executed and thus never added.

**What I tried:**

I tried multiple ways. 
I started with

```
  const mapRows = () => {
    return testvar.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      return <Row key={"Row" + rowIndex}>{mapColumns(row, rowIndex)}</Row>;
    });
  };

  // mapColumns

  const mapColumns = (row, rowIndex) => {
    return row.map((column, columnIndex) => {
      return (
        <Column key={"Column" + columnIndex}>
          <DisplayedElement />
        </Column>
      );
    });
  };
```

went over a direct `React.CreateElement` approach,
to now:

```
  const mapRows = () => {
    return testvar.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      return <Row key={"Row" + rowIndex} children={mapColumns(row, rowIndex)}/>;
    });
  };

    const mapCol = () => {
        return (<Stuff/>)
    }
```

In the end Neither of them worked.

The Example of the issue can be found here:
[Sandbox Example Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/code-example-5rf8j2?file=/src/WorkingArea.js)

Just a quick reminder, i am not a professional coder at this point, so my code may seem in a weird style or may contain unnecessary elements.

Anyway,

Thanks!

Edit1 15.07. : Changed JSFiddle to Code Sandbox to show the issue.
And Clarified example Code blocks to be more telling

Comment: Can you create a proper code sandbox (https://codesandbox.io/s/new)with all the code?

Comment: Thanks @AmilaSenadheera , I updated the Post and Created a massively simplified Code Sandbox for it. 
I was able to replicate it, while keeping it relatively simple. 

https://codesandbox.io/s/code-example-5rf8j2?file=/src/WorkingArea.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is the predefined prop called `children`.

When you wrap your elements as below,

```
<Row key={"Row" + rowIndex}>{mapColumns(row, rowIndex)}</Row>
```

then your `Row` component gets a prop with all the child elements in a prop called `children`. Use it to render them like below.

```
const Row = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Do the same for `Column`.

Working Demo

```js
const WorkingArea = () => {
  // this is the same as in my project
  let testvar = [
    [{ elementtype: "element A" }, { elementtype: "element B" }],
    [{ elementtype: "element C" }, { elementtype: "element D" }]
  ];

  const mapRows = () => {
    return testvar.map((row, rowIndex) => {
      return <Row key={"Row" + rowIndex}>{mapColumns(row, rowIndex)}</Row>;
    });
  };

  // mapColumns

  const mapColumns = (row, rowIndex) => {
    return row.map((column, columnIndex) => {
      return (
        <Column key={"Column" + columnIndex}>
          <DisplayedElement type={column.elementtype} />
        </Column>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="builder px-2">
      <h3>Formular</h3>
      <form className="mainForm">
        <div className="dropArea border rounded p-3">{mapRows()}</div>
        <button
          type="submit"
          className="btn btn-primary mt-1"
          onClick={(e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
          }}
        >
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
  );
};

// Other Smaller Components, now in the same file for easier fiddle.

const Row = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="row" style={{ display: "flex", flexDirection: "row" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const Column = ({ children }) => {
  // Contains a lot of other react-dnd functions, probably not necessary thus skipped
  return (
    <div className="col" style={{ padding: "10px" }}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );
};

const DisplayedElement = ({ type }) => {
  return <div>{type}</div>;
};


ReactDOM.render(<WorkingArea />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks! 

They way i did understand it now is, default HTML Tags (DIV, HR, H1, ...) are known in style and can be wrapped without children tag. 
But on Custom Components containing more than one HTML element, this doesnt work, thus the "children" property is necessary. 

I did not find a good source, thus i may have not noticed that i need to pass children on in code. For HTML element it seemed to do it automatically, which i supposed it could do as well with other elements, since they all have opening and closing tags ( `<Element></Element>` of which it couldve taken the mid, but didnt.

Comment: Yes, your understanding is right. Reacts Docs(https://reactjs.org/docs/getting-started.html) are really reader-friendly. They are many examples of common patterns there. I recommend reading it and that will save more time for you